# Using pyspark to create a segment array from a flat record

Tags: arraylist, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, record

I have a sparsely populated table with values for various segments for unique user ids. I need to create an array with unique_id and relevant segment headers only

Please note that this is just an indicative dataset. I have several hundreds of segments like these.

```
------------------------------------------------
| user_id   | seg1 | seg2 | seg3 | seg4 | seg5 |
------------------------------------------------
| 100       |   M  |  null|   25 |  null|  30  |
| 200       |  null|  null|   43 |  null|  250 |
| 300       |   F  |  3000|  null|  74  |  null|
------------------------------------------------
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
-------------------------------
| user_id| segment_array      |
-------------------------------
| 100    | [seg1, seg3, seg5] |
| 200    | [seg3, seg5]       |
| 300    | [seg1, seg2, seg4] |
-------------------------------
```

Is there any function available in pyspark of pyspark-sql to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find the direct way but you can do this.

```
cols= df.columns[1:]

r = df.withColumn('array', array(*[when(col(c).isNotNull(), lit(c)).otherwise('notmatch') for c in cols])) \
  .withColumn('array', array_remove('array', 'notmatch'))
r.show()
+-------+----+----+----+----+----+------------------+
|user_id|seg1|seg2|seg3|seg4|seg5|             array|
+-------+----+----+----+----+----+------------------+
|    100|   M|null|  25|null|  30|[seg1, seg3, seg5]|
|    200|null|null|  43|null| 250|      [seg3, seg5]|
|    300|   F|3000|null|  74|null|[seg1, seg2, seg4]|
+-------+----+----+----+----+----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way but I'd attack it this way:

There's the `collect_set` function which will always give you a unique value across a list of values you aggregate over.

do a union for each segment on:

```
df_seg_1 = df.select(
  'user_id', 
  fn.when(
    col('seg1').isNotNull(), 
    lit('seg1)
  ).alias('segment')
)
# repeat for all segments

df = df_seg_1.union(df_seg_2).union(...)

df.groupBy('user_id').agg(collect_list('segment'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Hans. This won't help as I have several hundreds of segments :(

Comment: it may affect speed but you can loop over something like `[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('seg')]`